# Is this random conditional possible with CSS preprocessor Stylus?

Tags: css, stylus

I have a random function in Stylus:

```
random(min,max)
   return floor(math(0, 'random')*(max - min + 1) + min)
```

I am using it like this to generate a random z-index on an element:

```
for i in (1..10) 
   .x{i}
      z-index random(-99, 99)
```

Now I want a conditional **on the same element if** the z-index is, for example > 0... Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by saving this random value to the variable and then reusing it both in condition and at `z-index`:

```
random($min, $max)
  return floor(math(0, 'random') * ($max - $min + 1) + $min)

for $i in (1..10)
  $random_value = random(-99, 99)
  .x{$i}
    z-index: $random_value

    if $random_value > 0
      background: lime
```

Comment: You can achieve the same without declaring a variable if you use stylus' property lookup: ```if @z-index > 0```